# Regular expression theory

Tags: regex

I have a little problem with [RE theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory).

Given an alphabet {0, 1}, I have to create a regular expression that matches all string that does NOT contain the substring 111.

I'm not able to get the point, also for simplier substring like 00.

Edit: The solution must contains only the three standard operation: concatenation, alternation, kleene star, as you can see in the wiki link

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the language you want to regexify is not allowed to contain three or more consecutive 1's. Such a regexp could be `(110|10|0*)*|1|11|0*1|0*11`

Comment: maybe, i think we need to add to your RE some special cases, like 1 11 001 011 010... right?

Comment: Yep, these strings are not captured by my proposition.

Comment: As a side note: it's always hard to find a regex that does NOT match something. The hard part is figuring out what you do want to match. In this case, the point is matching 2 or less `1`s with `0`s between them.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
{ε|1}{ε|1}{ε|{0{ε|1}{ε|1}}*}
```

Comment: Impressive. I think this is the one I need. Tried on http://www.oursland.net/projects/regexp/ and it seems to work very well.

Comment: Took me a while to realize that this equals `1?1?(01?1?)*`, or in a different syntax `1{0,2}(01{0,2})*`. +1

Comment: As these regexs don't use anchors such as ^ and $ for beginning and end, why do they not match any string with an arbitrary tail 10110010111111111, the regex matches the first bit, the 111 we don't want would be ignored - at least that's how the perl family would work.

Comment: @djna, the regex in my answer is in the formal language of RE theory, which doesn't use anchors; the expression must match the WHOLE string. I think we can assume that Pumbaa80 omitted the anchors in his comment for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days when we didn't have the ?! negative lookahead facility I would use a negation match. So for grep I would

```
grep -v (pattern I'm searching for) someFile.txt
```

which would give the lines in the file that don't contain the pattern.

In perl I would use the

```
!~
```

negation matcher rather than the usual

```
=~
```

I don't know which regex variant you are using, but I'm struggling to see a way to solve your problem without either an overall negation or a ?! negative lookahead.

matcher.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, please read my edit section (i forgot it, sorry) in my post